# How am I suppose to manage the app state in Win32 API on Dart?

Tags: dart, winapi

I'm trying to make a really simple application in Dart using Win32 APIs (Personal challenge).

I was trying to make an app that will perform some simple task in Dart, and in the meanwhile, it will show the progress on a progress bar, and the "progress description" on a non-user-editable text box, like this:

```
Retrieving message... 
Searching message in database...
Sending message...
Process finished.
```

So, I have to make a simple struct which contains the progress of the progress bar and a UTF16 text for the progress text.

I was trying like so:

```cpp
Pointer<StateInfo> pState;
 if (uMsg == WM_CREATE) {
    Pointer<CREATESTRUCT> pCreate = Pointer<CREATESTRUCT>.fromAddress(lParam);
    pState = pCreate.ref.lpCreateParams.cast<StateInfo>();
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, pState.cast<LONG_PTR>().value);
 } else {
    pState = GetStateInfo(hwnd);
 }
```

For the first part, I've just followed what [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-), modifying it, and I don't think it works, but for the `else`-part, I can't find any documentation and the linter (also the Dart compiler) says that `GetStateInfo()` doesn't exist.

How would I do this?

Comment: There is no `GetStateInfo()` in the MSDN example you linked to. That needs to be a function you write yourself to wrap `GetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)`

Comment: Oh sure, you're right about this, thanks. But now another problem, how do i do the first part of the code? i can't find any remplacement of reinterpret_cast

Comment: You already know what the replacement is, because you are already using it: `Pointer.framAddress()` and `cast<>`

Comment: Oh, i didn't really thinked to get that part right, thanks for the help. If i'll need any furhter help with State Management i'll ask here.